# In an array match a value with key and return it's value of array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to search a value in and array and match with key if key exits returns it's value like if value `'foo'` search in an array `$array`  and if `'foo'` found in an array returns its' value `1`.

```
$array = array('foo'=>1, 'foo2'=>2, 'foo3'=>3);
```

I try with an `array_key_exists()` function but we know it return true or false value but I have  need its value.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

(Here i just simply flip the array with [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) to search the value in the keys with [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php))

```
<?php

    $array = array('foo'=>1, 'foo2'=>2, 'foo3'=>3);

    if(in_array("foo", array_flip($array)))
        echo $array["foo"];

?>
```